# Sort computed areas

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps and I get all markers that are close a locaton (lat, lng).
This point is OK.

Now i want to sort theses markers, like in SQL we can do a "order by distance ASC" for example.

I saw in javascript have a method call sort() which can sort some numbers asc or desc for example.

markers have some informations: name, title, gender, city, postcode ...

my code:

```
 var nbMeters = 50000;  

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var myMarker = markers[i];

         coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(myMarker.lat, myMarker.lng);
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coords, coords2);


  if(distance <= nbMeters) {   

     alert(myMarker.name);
    //OK my marker is close the variable coords, good !
    //But how to know which marker is the closer, which is the second, the third ... and the less closer ??

  }

}
```

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try sth like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var myMarker = markers[i];

    coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(myMarker.lat, myMarker.lng);
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(coords, coords2);
    markers[i].distance = distance;
}

function sortMarkers(marker1, marker2) {
    return marker1.distance - marker2.distance;
}

markers.sort(sortMarkers);
```

It's untested and based on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp